# Square of the sum minus sum of the squares in J (or how to take the train?)

Tags: j

Still in the learning process of J... The problem to solve is now to [express the square of the sum minus the sum of the squares of natural integers](http://projecteuler.net/problem=6).

The naive solution is

```
(*:+/>:i.100) - (+/*:>:i.100)
```

Now, I want to use a fork to be able to write the list `>:i.100` only one time. My fork should like to:

```
  h
/   \
f   g
|   |
x   x
```

where `f` is the square of the sum, `g` is the sum of the squares, and `h` is minus. So, naively, I wrote:

```
((*:+/) - (+/*:)) >:i.100
```

but it gives me a domain error. Why? I also tried:

```
(+/ (*: - +/) :*) >: i.100
```

and this time, it gives me a long list of numbers... I guess it has something to do with the `@` conjunction, but I still don't figure out what the At does... Continuing my quest, I finally got

```
((+/*+/) - +/@:*:) >:i.100
```

but I don't like the fact I manually compute the squares instead of using the `*:` operator, and I don't really understand why I need the `@:` conjunction. Could somebody gives me some light about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(+/*:)` and `(*:+/)` don't do what you think they do.

Actually, your `f` is `Q (S x)` (square of sum of x) and your `g` is `S (Q x)` (sum of square of x). You [can see](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/08.htm) that for any f,g it is `f (g y)` = `(f @: g) y`.

So, you can write

```
(Q (S x)) h (S (Q x))
```

as

```
((Q @: S) x) h ((S @: Q) X)
```

which is *now* equivalent to

```
(f x) h (g x)
```

or

```
(f h g) x
```

Thus,

```
((*: @: (+/)) - (+/ @: *:)) >: i.1000
```

Note also that `*: @: (+/)` is not the same as `*: @: +/`, since `+/` is not *one* verb (like `*:`) but a composite verb from a verb (`+`) and an adverb (`/`).

Comment: BTW, you can omit all parenthesis *but* `(+/)`: `f =: *:@:(+/) - +/@:*:`; `f >:i.1000`.

Comment: Thank you for your your very clear explanation. I see that my mistake was to think `+/` was like a verb.