# Simple hook is not executed as expected

Tags: j

I define `a` as an array and find the running max:

```
  a =: 3 1 4 1 5 9 2
  >./\ a
3 3 4 4 5 9 9
```

Then I want to filter out duplicates. I know that nub (`~.`) does this, so I try:

```
  ~. >./\ a
3 4 5 9
```

It works but I don't know why. I thought it should not work. `/` and `\` are adverbs, so `(>./\)` is a verb. We then have: `f g y`, which is a hook, and it should be executed as `y f (g y)`. Obviously it does not work that way.

Instead, it's executed as `~. (>./\)` (i.e. `f (g y)`), like it was `~. @ (>./\)`. So what's going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J executes statements right to left so your `~. >./\ a` is equivalent to:

```
~. (((>./) \) a)
```

It would be a hook if it was parenthesized like:

```
(~.  ((>./) \)) a
```

Some relevant discussions: [function composition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17113606/349708) and [how to take the train](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15160502/349708).

*Edit*: To make this clearer, `f g y` is *always* `f (g y)`. If you want the hook, you have to write `(f g) y`.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, now these concepts are much clearer!